# How can I group and reformat a dataframe based on a column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
        cardio     variable  value
0            0  cholesterol      0
1            1  cholesterol      1
2            1  cholesterol      1
3            1  cholesterol      0
4            0  cholesterol      0
...        ...          ...    ...
419995       0   overweight      1
419996       1   overweight      1
419997       1   overweight      1
419998       1   overweight      1
419999       0   overweight      0
```

How can I split and group it based on the value of the "cardio" column and also get the counts? Like so:

```
   cardio variable  value  total
0       0   active      0   6378
1       0   active      1  28643
2       0     alco      0  33080
...
    cardio    variable  value  total
21       1  overweight      1  24440
22       1       smoke      0  32050
23       1       smoke      1   2929
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try a dict comprehension :

The idea is to first create a group for each cardio group `df.groupby('cardio')`.

Then apply your operation on each group, in this instance `size()` and return it to its own dataframe.

We use a dictionary to hold the various dataframes in a single container as opposed to disparate variables.

```
data_dict = {
    f"cardio_{cardio}": data.groupby(["variable", "value"]).size().reset_index(name='counts')
    for cardio, data in df.groupby("cardio")
}

data_dict['cardio_0']

      variable  value  counts
0  cholesterol      0  2
1   overweight      0  1
2   overweight      1  1
```

---

```
data_dict['cardio_1']

      variable  value  counts
0  cholesterol      0  1
1  cholesterol      1  2
2   overweight      1  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by the values of cardio column:

```
df = pd.read_csv('../')
df = df.sort_values(by=cardio)
```

Splitting the dataframe by the values of cardio:

```
df_cardio_0 = df[df['cardio']==0]
df_cardio_1 = df[df['cardio']==1]
```

Comment: How can I get the total counts as shown in my question?

Comment: length of each dataframe is the count. So len(df_cardio_0) or len(df[df['cardio']==0]) would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function to concatenate the filter frame you want from your split column.

```
Def Group(column,  Frame):
      Return PD.concat([Frame[Frame[column]==0],  Frame[Frame[column]==1]
```

Then pass your dataframe to this function.

```
Group("cardio",  df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
df0 = df.query('cardio==0').groupby(['cardio','variable','value']).size().reset_index()
print(df0)

df1 = df.query('cardio==1').groupby(['cardio','variable','value']).size().reset_index()
print(df1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dataframe is df_1 you can use groupby to reshape your dataframe

```
df_2 = df_1.groupby(['cardio','variable','value']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
```

[Resulte will be as follows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hL4Kv.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
df_cat.groupby(['variable','cardio','value'])['variable'].count().reset_index(name='total')
```

**which will give us the answer**

[image]